# Loading images stored on linode object storage in react

Tags: reactjs, django, image, linode, python-django-storages

I am creating an ui for a django project and I have all my static files uploaded to a linode object storage and in django I can load images and view them with no problem but in react I fetch the url using an api from django but when I try to render it I get a 403 access forbidden. How do I set the access keys in react to grab the images?